# onFocusChange event seems to be cancelled by onValueChanged event

Tags: flutter, events

If in the following snippet I leave the `TextField` by clicking on the `CupertinoSegmentedControl`, I would expect that first the `onFocusChange` event of the `TextField` and then the `onValueChanged` event of the `CupertinoSegmentedControl` would be called.

However, there is no evidence that the `onFocusChange` change is called, even not if I place a timer before the `onValueChanged` of `CupertinoSegmentedControl`. The `print` statement for example is not executed. What am I doing wrong?

Reason for this possibly funny set-up: I have a multi-page form. I am doing the validation inside a BloC. Especially if someone edits a task, one might move by clicking on the progress tabs instead of the save and continue buttons. Therefore I thought the easiest way to support this is by saving the data of each TextField when the user puts the focus away. This works fine, unless one clicks on a value inside `CupertinoSegmentedControl`

```dart
Column( // task type
  children: [
    Focus(child: TextField(
      controller: titleController,
      decoration: createDecoration("Title of task", widget.state.validationData.titleHelper),
      ),
      onFocusChange: (hasFocus) {
print("TASK TITLE has focus: $hasFocus");
        if (!hasFocus) {
          taskEditBloc.add(TaskEditDataEntered(taskData:
            widget.state.taskData!.copyWith(title: () => titleController.text)));
        }
      },
    ),
    CupertinoSegmentedControl(
      children: {
        0: const Text('A',),
        1: const Text('B',),
      },
      groupValue: taskType,
      onValueChanged: (value) {
        Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 200), () {
          taskEditBloc.add(TaskEditDataEntered(taskData:
            widget.state.taskData!.copyWith(taskType: () => value)));
        });},
    ),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

As future reference for others:

It does not seem to cancel but instead when clicking on `CupertinoSegmentedControl`, the latter does not take focus and as such the `TextField` does not loose focus.

The same is true when clicking on the tabs. Since I did not fid any elegant way to take away the focus from the text field I decided to solve this with a more complex BLoC logic. TextFields set the state of the widget, clicks on buttons or tabs trigger an event emitting a state that informs a BlocListener to send the data of that tab to the BLoC - before the BLoC emits the signal to show a different tab in case of positive validation